# Autosuggest from php

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

I have a php file that reads data from my mysqldb as a json array.
The data should be displayed if the user types in 3 characters.

JS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/demos.css"> //JQuery AutoSuggest Css
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = <?php include("/php/getAllRecipes.php"); ?>;


        $( "#searchrecipes" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
        <input id="searchrecipes" type="text" name="searchrecipes" class="searchinput" style="margin-left: 850px; margin-top: 0px; width:170px; background: #fff url(images/search_icon.png) no-repeat 100%;" placeholder="Suchen..."></input>
        <input type="submit"1 name="buttonsenden" style="display:none;" value="" width: 5px></input>
```

Problem:

We have to get the data into the array in our JS calles "availableTags".

Comment: What is the HTML source of the page as it's received by your browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var availableTags = JSON.parse(<?php include("/php/getAllRecipes.php"); ?>);
```

That is assuming that your PHP file outputs valid JSON, **WITH** surrounding quotes.
Such as: `echo '"'.addslashes(json_encode($data)).'"';`

Comment: Why would you need too parse it, would it not just be a normal inline declaration of an object?